# gnuplot change color of line1 with reference to sign of line2

Tags: conditional-statements, gnuplot

I have 3 columns in my data. The first being a date. I want to plot the 2nd column but change its colour depending on value in 3rd column.

```
If 3rd column is:
     Positive:  Black
     Negative:  Red
     zero:      Yellow
```

This is what I am trying:

```
set palette model RGB defined ( 0 'yellow', 1 'red', 2 'black' )
plot "output2.txt" u 1:2:( $3 < 0 ? 1 : ( $3 > 0 ? 2 : 0 ) )  w lines palette axes x1y1
```

But I don't get Red ever, even though Column 3 has negative numbers.

EDIT 1

I also get it to work SOMETIMES, but here is a case where it does not:

```
$ cat t.txt
1 1 1000000
2 2 1000000
3 3 1000000
4 4 -1000000
5 5 -1000000
6 6 -1000000
7 7 -1000000
```

Here is my gnu script:

```
$ cat test.gnu
set terminal wxt size 1500,900
set style fill transparent solid 0.50 noborder
set key font ",6"
set palette model RGB defined ( 0 'yellow', 1 'red', 2 'black' )
plot "t.txt" u 1:2:( $3 < 0 ? 1 : ( $3 > 0 ? 2 : 0 ) )  w lines palette axes x1y1
```

This is how I call it from cygwin:

```
~/wgnuplot -e "load \"test.gnu\"" -persist
```

This is the result  (The yellow line should be red) :

[image]

Comment: That works fine for me. Can you show a few lines from your data file which show the problem?

Comment: @Christoph   See EDIT 1 please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values given in the palette aren't absolute values, but the lowest number (here 0) is mapped to the minimum of the `cbrange` and the highest number (here 2) is mapped to the cb-maximum.

The values given in the third column of the `using` statement, however, are absolute color values and depend on the `cbrange`. In your problematic case the autoscaling sets a `cbrange` of `[1:2]`, so that `1` gives yellow, `1.5` gives red and `2` gives black.

Just use `set cbrange [0:2]` to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than `palette`, I would use `linecolor variable`:

```
plot 'test.txt' u 1:2:($3 < 0 ? 2 : ( $3 > 0 ? 3 : 1 )) w lines lc variable
```

The numbers returned from your ternary operator expression (1, 2, 3) should correspond to line styles that you set.

In this case, I think it's:

```
set style line 1 lc rgb "yellow"
set style line 2 lc rgb "red"
set style line 3 lc rgb "black"
```

(tested with the following data):

```
1 2 3
2 2 3
3 2 0
4 2 0
5 2 12
6 2 -15
7 2 -23
```

Note that this works well if you have highly sampled data.  Poorly sampled data can make for a funny looking plot since the line segment is colored based on the value of the data at the second of the endpoints encountered in the file.

For what it's worth, I get the same result if I use:

```
set palette defined (1 'yellow', 2 'red', 3 'black')
plot 'test.txt' u 1:3:($3 < 0 ? 2 : ( $3 > 0 ? 3 : 1 )) w lines lc palette z
```

(only with a colorbar and key this time).